# How To Style MahApps Window Grid?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, mahapps.metro

I'm using Mahapps UI toolkit for my WPF application, and I need my grid which is placed inside MetroWindow to change its color when application is not active as MetroWindow does. I've tried several solutions, but in vain:

```
<Grid Background="{DynamicResource AccentColorBrush}" >
                <TextBlock Text="Test" Foreground="#FFFFFF"  VerticalAlignment="Center" Padding="10,0,0,0"/>
</Grid>
```

This solution either sets grid color as AccentColorBrush

```
<Grid Background="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=controls:MetroWindow}, Path=WindowTitleBrush}" >
                <TextBlock Text="Test" Foreground="#FFFFFF"  VerticalAlignment="Center" Padding="10,0,0,0"/>
</Grid>
```

I can also set grid color as inactive with NonActiveWindowTitleBrush property

```
<Grid Background="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=controls:MetroWindow}, Path=NonActiveWindowTitleBrush}" >
                    <TextBlock Text="Test" Foreground="#FFFFFF"  VerticalAlignment="Center" Padding="10,0,0,0"/>
</Grid>
```

I'll be thankful for any help.

Regards, Dmitry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<Controls:MetroWindow x:Class="MahApps.Metro.Application12.MainWindow"
                  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                  xmlns:Controls="http://metro.mahapps.com/winfx/xaml/controls"
                  xmlns:Custom="http://metro.mahapps.com/winfx/xaml/shared" 
                  Title="MainWindow"
                  Height="350" 
                  Width="525">

<Controls:MetroWindow.Resources>

    <Style x:Key="GridStyle1" TargetType="{x:Type Grid}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource AccentColorBrush}"/>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsActive, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Controls:MetroWindow}}}" Value="False">
                <Setter Property="Background"  Value="{StaticResource GrayBrush3}"/>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>

</Controls:MetroWindow.Resources>

<Grid x:Name="grid1" Margin="50" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Height="232" Width="409" Style="{StaticResource GridStyle1}">

    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="32" Text="{Binding IsActive, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Controls:MetroWindow}}}"/>

</Grid>
```

[image]

Comment: Yeah, I've already made the same. I thought some dynamic brush is available and ect. Anyway thanks a lot!

Comment: Maybe there is one.... post a follow-up question linking back to this solution and explain that although this is working, you're looking for an alternative solution using a _dynamic brush_. I don't know of it but someone else might.